# How do I check which radio button in a group of radio buttons is selected in a Jinja2 HTML Template?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I have a jinja2 html template that has two groups of radio buttons, which we will call radio_group_1 and radio_group_2. Each button in radio_group_2 is mapped to a corresponding button in radio_group_1 on a value. What I am trying to do is when the user selects a radio button in radio_group_2, I want the radio button selection in radio_group_1 to automatically change to its corresponding radio button.

I have tried using javascript to no avail.

Thanks for any help!

```
<h2>Testing radio functionality</h2>
<div>
<input name="radio_group_1" id="1" value="button1" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('1','button1');" />Button 1
<input name="radio_group_1" id="2"value="button2" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('2','button2');" />Button 2
<input name="radio_group_1"id="3" value="button3" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('3','button3');" />Button 3
<br />
</div>

<div>
<input name="radio_group_2" id="4" value="button4" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('4','button1');" />Button 4
<input name="radio_group_2" id="5" value="button5" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('5','button1');" />Button 5
<input name="radio_group_2" id="6" value="button6" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('6','button1');" />Button 6
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function radioChange(id,radioButton,radioArray)
  {

  radiobtn = document.getElementById(id);
  radiobtn.checked = true;
  new_number = Number(id) + 3
  new_number.toString(10)
radiobtn = document.getElementById(new_number);
  radiobtn.checked = true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your code relates to the radio group

Comment: I just added some code that I wrote now - would this work in Jinja?

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with your code is that, you're passing two values in the method call **radioChange('1','button1')** whereas your method prototype accepts three values because of which js was failing to find a radioChange method which accepts two parameters. Just remove **radioArray** from the method prototype and it's fixed.

```html
<h2>Testing radio functionality</h2>
<div>
<input name="radio_group_1" id="1" value="button1" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('1','button1');" />Button 1
<input name="radio_group_1" id="2"value="button2" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('2','button2');" />Button 2
<input name="radio_group_1"id="3" value="button3" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('3','button3');" />Button 3
<br />
</div>

<div>
<input name="radio_group_2" id="4" value="button4" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('4','button1');" />Button 4
<input name="radio_group_2" id="5" value="button5" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('5','button1');" />Button 5
<input name="radio_group_2" id="6" value="button6" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('6','button1');" />Button 6
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function radioChange(id,radioButton)
  {

  radiobtn = document.getElementById(id);
  radiobtn.checked = true;
  new_number = Number(id) + 3
  new_number.toString(10)
radiobtn = document.getElementById(new_number);
  radiobtn.checked = true;
}
</script>
```